# Membership testing with hash collision for sets in python

Tags: python, hash, set

Here is my class which I intentionally made it so that hash collision occurs:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.name} - {self.age})'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('__eq__ called for', self)
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        print('__hash__ called for', self)
        return 1


obj1 = Person('Soroush', 25)
obj2 = Person('John', 23)
print('\n--------Creation of set---------\n')
s = {obj1, obj2}
print(s)
print('\n-------Membership testing-------\n')
print(obj2 in s)
```

output:

```
--------Creation of set---------

__hash__ called for (Soroush - 25)
__hash__ called for (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Soroush - 25)
{(Soroush - 25), (John - 23)}

-------Membership testing-------

__hash__ called for (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Soroush - 25)
True
```

*My question is from "Membership testing" part of the output:

In `obj2 in s` statement, python first calculates the hash of `obj2` (good, first line of output), then because `obj1` and `obj2` have the same hash, python is going to see if they are the same items or not so `__eq__` of the `obj1` is called(second line of the output). They are not ! I intentionally returned `False` for all instances. So python is continue checking the **probe sequence**. Here again the hashes are equal! why python doesn't call `__eq__` of `obj2` to see if those items are equal or not ?

I expected to see `__eq__ called for (John - 23)` in third line and also because `obj2` is not equal to `obj2` , last line of the output should be `False`. like:

```
print(obj2 == obj2)
```

output :

```
__eq__ called for (John - 23)
False
```

So, why there is no `__eq__ called for (John - 23)` and why `True`? They are not the same items(same thing happened a second ago with `obj1`) .

Comment: Maybe since `obj2 is obj2` the `__eq__` method is not called?

Comment: @qouify so you mean there is a identity checking statement in source code, which first sees if the ID's are equal or not ?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d315c311676888201f4a3576e4ee3698684a3a2/Objects/setobject.c#L75

Comment: @KellyBundy Is it a normal behavior that none of the items in the set are equal to what we're searching for, but we get `True` back? or am I missing something obvious here...

Comment: @KellyBundy Interesting--this seems inconsistent with how `dict` handles this, which I thought explicitly does not use object identity for handling hash collisions.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Depends on what you mean with "normal". I'd say it's unusual, but that's because of your objects. Usually, objects equal themselves. Probably the most famous counterexample is `float('nan')`.

Comment: Nevermind, it does indeed use identity for dict lookups too.  In fact it doesn't even bother comparing hashes in this case, IIUC: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d315c311676888201f4a3576e4ee3698684a3a2/Objects/dictobject.c#L813

Comment: Also see the documentation: "[For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All built-in container types check *object identity* before testing (potentially expensive) object equality. This behavior is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or
> collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Of course, that isn't how hash-based containers actually check membership. Again, this is an optimization, this spares potentially expensive equality operations, consider checking the equality of two large strings.

Here's a built-in that works the same way, the famously problematic floating point NaN:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan == nan
False
>>> nan is nan
True
>>> nan is float('nan')
False
>>> nan == float('nan')
False
```

And this results in the following behavior with sets:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> myset = {nan}
>>> nan in myset
True
>>> float('nan') in myset
False
```

Note, it is false when we create a *new* `float` object.

Comment: You already answered my another question in advance... that statement from document implies linear searching that is obviously not the case with hash-based containers... Maybe it would be better if they rewrite that line in document.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary eh, not really. I think it is clear that they did not mean to imply that, but in any event, it definitely isn't the case

Answer (score 1):

`So, why there is no __eq__ called for (John - 23)`

This can be easily achieved by using `for in`

```py
for i in s:
    print(i)
    if i == obj2:
        print('equal', i)
```

```
-------Membership testing-------

(John - 23)
__eq__ called for (John - 23) (John - 23)
(Soroush - 25)
__eq__ called for (Soroush - 25) (John - 23)
```

But obviously, this is not what you want, let's add another person and try the `in` operator

```py
obj1 = Person('Soroush', 25)
obj2 = Person('John', 23)
obj3 = Person('Kite', 23)
print('\n--------Creation of set---------\n')
s = {obj3, obj2, obj1}
print(s)
print('\n-------Membership testing-------\n')
print(obj2 in s)
```

```
-------Membership testing-------
__hash__ called for (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Kite - 23) (John - 23)
True
```

Now by changing the set element position

```py
.
.
s = {obj3, obj1, obj2}
.
.
```

```
__hash__ called for (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Kite - 23) (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Soroush - 25) (John - 23)
True
```

From this, I came to the conclusion that the `True` is coming from the check of `some parameter` for the 3rd element (last example). And that is most obviously the `id` or memory location in case CPython. Because for this case

```py
.
.
print(Person('John', 23) in s)
.
.
```

```
__hash__ called for (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Kite - 23) (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (Soroush - 25) (John - 23)
__eq__ called for (John - 23) (John - 23)
False
```

You get false, because `id(Person('John', 23))` is obviously not same as `obj2`. Similar behavior can be reproduced in `for in` instead of `==` use `is`

```py
obj1 = Person('Soroush', 25)
obj2 = Person('John', 23)
print('\n--------Creation of set---------\n')
s = {obj2, obj1}
print(s)
print('\n-------Membership testing-------\n')

for i in s:
    print(i)
    if i is obj2:
        print('equal', i)
     

print(obj2 in s)
```

```
-------Membership testing-------

(John - 23)
equal (John - 23)          ------------------------
(Soroush - 25)                                     |
                                                   |
                                                   |--you are missing this output in `in` check
__hash__ called for (John - 23)                    |
True      -----------------------------------------|
```